# Should answers be closed because they are wrong?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I'm trying to become a better reviewer and I am seeing posts in the 'Low Quality Posts' review queue that are flagged for review 'Because of their length and content'.

Sometimes I see answers there that are flagged for review where the only thing I can see wrong with the answer is this it appears to be incorrect, or the solution didn't work.

### My Question

Examples aside (or take the simplest case where there is a clear error or false assumption in the answer), is this a valid reason for recommending deletion or should we leave the 'veracity' of an answer up to the community by voting on it?

I have been marking these 'Looks OK' but I want to be sure that I am not missing something here and burning up someone's flags.

FWIW I am not seeing any gross amount of these scenarios, just a few here and there.

Comment: Related - [When to vote to delete an answer](/questions/4772/when-to-vote-to-delete-an-answer)

Answer (score 3):

Answers can't be closed, that's a state that only applies to questions, but I assume you mean deleted. If the answer misunderstood the question and isn't addressing what the question is asking, it should be deleted. If it understood the question but got the answer wrong, it should be downvoted, but we don't delete answers just for being wrong. At one point someone suggested adding a [disabled "wrong answer" option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202343/145982) to the flag dialog to help avoid "not an answer" flags in that situation.